# count the number of rows with a particular column value

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called votes.

```
ID              int(11) pk ai
candidate_id    int(11)
region          varchar(75)
```

Can I get an result with an sql statement with something like

```
West 46
East 75
North 28
etc...
```

West, East being regions...

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear to me. Do you want a sum of votes, or is 46 the candidate id?

Comment: 46 is the sum of votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT region, COUNT(region)
FROM votes
GROUP BY region ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Hmm, elaborating on your request for totals of votes per candidate, will depend on how your data is laid out. Do you simply have one row per vote for a candidate, if so, then I'd try (although I haven't tested);

```
SELECT region, COUNT(region), candidate_id, COUNT(candidate_id)
FROM votes
GROUP BY region, candidate_id ORDER BY 2 DESC, 4 DESC
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Also can we do it something like

x - 24
y - 22

where x and y are candidates from a particular region.

Comment: Try the updated statement. Not sure about the commas in the order by clause...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want one string, containing both fields, you can use MySQL's CONCAT function to concatenate.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT region, SUM(*) as votes_count, CONCAT(region, " ", votes_count) FROM votes
```

[More info on CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Region
, SUM(Candidate_ID) -- Assumes that the SUM of this equals total votes
FROM Votes
GROUP BY Region
```

Comment: Distinct is not needed with a Group By.